# .htaccess 301 redirect url´s with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem redirecting my url´s with parameters.

My url´s look like this:

*www.my-site.com/catalogo.php?cat=xxx*

and it´s rewriting to:

*www.my-site/xxx*

That´s working fine the rewriting! But know, google is indexing both url´s and have to make a rule to redirect the url with parameters to the friendly url. Had tryed many solutions that find googling, but only one worked and was redirecting to domain root.

I want to do this redirects:

**www.my-site.com/catalogo.php?cat=xxx**  to **www.my-site/xxx**

**www.my-site.com/catalogo.php?cat=xxx&scat=yyy**  to **www.my-site/xxx/yyy**

**www.my-site.com/product.php?cat=xxx&scat=yyy&name=zzz&id=xyz** to **www.my-site/xxx/yyy/zzz/xyz**

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /catalogo\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /catalogo\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&scat=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /catalogo\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&scat=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]
```